# How specific to get on design document?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a design document for a security subsystem, to be written in C++. I've created a class diagram and sequence diagrams for the major use cases. I've also specified the public attributes, associations and methods for each of the classes. But, I haven't drilled the method definitions down to the C++ level yet. Since I'm new to C++ , as is the other developer, I wonder if it might not make sense go ahead and specify to this level. Thoughts?

edit: Wow - completely against, unanimous.  I was thinking about, for example, the whole business about specifying const vs. non-const, passing references, handling default constructor and assigns, and so forth. I do believe it's been quite helpful to spec this out to this level of detail so far. I definitely have gotten a clearer idea of how the system will work. Maybe if I just do a few methods, as an example, before diving into the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're new, it probably makes sense *not* to drill down.

Reason: You're still figuring out the language and how things are best structured.  That means you'll make mistakes initially and you'll want to correct them without constantly updating the documentation.

Comment: Accepted Jason's answer because of the point about not having to constantly go back to the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't recommend going to this level, but then again you've already gone past where I would go in a design specification.  My personal feeling is that putting a lot of effort into detailed design up-front is going to be wasted as you find out in developing code that your guesses as to how the code will work are wrong.  I would stick with a high-level design and think about using TDD (test driven development) to guide the low-level design and implementation.

Comment: +1 for TDD, especially for a pair of novice C++ programmers. There are going to be heaps of errors, and a strict suite of tests will be the best defence against them.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it makes no sense at all, and that you have gone too far already. If you are new to C++ you are in no position to write a detailed design document for a C++ project. I would recommend you try to implement what you already have in C++, learn by the inevitable mistakes (like public attributes) and then go back and revise it.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on who the design document is targeted at. If it's for a boss who is non-technical, then you are good with what you have.

If it's for yourself, then you are using the tool to help you, so you decide. I create method level design docs when I am creating a project, but it's at a high level so I can figure out what the features of the various classes should be. I've found that across languages, the primary functionalities of a class have little to do with the programming language we are working in. Some of the internal details and functions required *certainly* vary due to the chosen language, but those are implementation details that I *don't* bother with during the design phase.

It certainly helps me to know that for instance an authorization class might have an authenticate function that takes a User object as a parameter. I don't really care during design that I might need an internal string md5 function wrapper to accomplish some specific goal. I find out about that while coding.

The goal of initial design is to get organized so you can make progress with clarity and forethought rather than tearing out and reimplementing the same function 4 times because you forgot some scenario due to not planning.

EDIT:  I work in PHP a lot, and I actually use PhpDoc to do some of the design docs, by simply writing the method signature with no implementation, then putting a detailed description of what the method should do in the method header comments. This helps anyone that is using my class in the future, because the design IS the documentation. I can also change the documentation if I do need to make some alterations while coding.

I work in php4 a lot, so I don't get to use interfaces. In php5, I create the interface, then implement it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to specify how the code should actually fit together is **in code**.  The design document is for other things that are not easily expressed in code.  You should use it for describing the actual need the program fills, How it interacts with users, what the constraints are in terms of hardware and operating systems.  Certainly describe the overall architecture of your application in a design document, but, for instance, the API should actually be described in the code that exposes the API.

Answer (score 0):

You have already gone far enough with the documentation part. As you still a beginner in C++, when you would understand the language, you might want to change the structure of your program. Then you would have to do changes in the documentation. I would suggest that you have already gone too far with the documentation. No need to drill more into it

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else says, you've gone way past where you need to go with the design. Do you have a good set of requirements to the simple true/false statement level that you derived that design from? You can design all day long, but if you don't have requirements that simply say WHAT you're going to do, it doesn't matter how good your design is.